# SQL: Grouping records by selected columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

My table looks like this (Name = TMaster)

```
A B C D
1 1 1 X
1 1 1 Y
1 1 1 Z
2 2 2 Y
3 3 3 Y
3 3 3 Z
```

I want to display it like this:

```
A B C DX DY DZ
1 1 1 X  Y  Z
2 2 2    Y
3 3 3    Y  Z
```

**Solution that I have tried:**

I tried to create a distinct table which would like this: (Name TUnique)

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Then tried to outer join it with original table using one of the columns (A or B or C). But it returns output like this:

```
A B C DX DY DZ
1 1 1 X  Y  Z
```

I tried Union operator as well but with no luck. Having ' ' as columns in the unique table created, but it ends up creating too many duplicate records.

Here's the SQL code that I've tried:

```
SELECT
    Ta.A,
    Ta.B,
    Ta.C,
    Tm1.D,
    Tm2.D,
    Tm3.D
FROM
    TUnique Ta,
    TUnique Tb,
    TUnique Tc,
    TMaster Tm1,
    TMaster Tm2,
    TMaster Tm3
WHERE
    Tm1.A = Ta.A (+)
    AND Tm1.D="X"
    Tm2.A = Tb.A (+)
    AND Tm2.D="Y"
    Tm3.A = Tc.A (+)
    AND Tm3.D="X";
```

This too returns same record.

```
SELECT
    Ta.A,
    Ta.B,
    Ta.C,
    Tm1.D,
    Tm2.D,
    Tm3.D
FROM
    TUnique Ta,
    TUnique Tb,
    TUnique Tc,
    TMaster Tm1,
    TMaster Tm2,
    TMaster Tm3
WHERE
    Tm1.A (+) = Ta.A 
    AND Tm1.D="X"
    Tm2.A (+) = Tb.A 
    AND Tm2.D="Y"
    Tm3.A (+) = Tc.A 
    AND Tm3.D="X";
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That strange outer join syntax is deprecated and product specific.

Comment: May (1,1,1) have several Y rows?

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` for outer joins

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot your `D` value:

```
SELECT A, B, C,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D='X' THEN D END) AS DX,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D='Y' THEN D END) AS DY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D='Z' THEN D END) AS DZ
FROM TMaster
GROUP BY A, B, C
```

Output

```
A   B   C   DX      DY  DZ
1   1   1   X       Y   Z
2   2   2   null    Y   null
3   3   3   null    Y   Z
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSvQ8usmyG2iMnEdfkJZd7/0)

Comment: . . The comment about blank strings is not appropriate for Oracle where empty strings *are* treated as `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for that. The question wasn't tagged Oracle when I answered it and I hadn't noticed the change. It's interesting behaviour; do you know why they do that?

Comment: . . Oracle pre-dates the standard.  It must've seemed like a good idea in the early 1980s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff like a lot of things! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `pivot` query :

```
select * 
  from
  ( select * from tab )
  pivot
  (
   max(D) for D in ( 'X' as dx, 'Y' as dy, 'Z' as dz )
  )
 order by A;


 A  B   C   DX  DY  DZ
 -  -   -   --  --  --
 1  1   1   X   Y   Z
 2  2   2       Y   
 3  3   3       Y   Z
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2317ca9f90189b13a7a4adc45b3f9380)</kbd>